# How to delay inside yield all?

Tags: redux-saga

How to delay in every map inside loop generator? It yield delay works 1 time. Maybe it shouldn't be `something.map`?

```
function* loop(param1, param2, param3) {
    try {
        const count = yield call(getCall, param1, param2)
        yield delay(150)
        return {
            id: param2,
            title: param3,
            count: param1
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

function* saga(action) {
    try {
        yield put(setIsLoadingAction(true))
        const something = yield select(selectSomethig)
        //loop here
        const data = yield all(
            something.map((someth) => loop(action.payload, someth.id, someth.title))
        )
        yield put(setSomething(data))
        yield put(setIsLoadingAction(false))
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify where you've used `delay`?

Comment: @jmargolisvt added deleay into `loop` generator

Comment: How do you know the `delay` is only running once?

Comment: @jmargolisvt because i set delay to 5 seconds and after 5 seconds delaying was 30 rest calls